# Why should IQueryProvider implementations throw NotSupportedExceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, interfaces, solid, linq

Searching the web, we can find plentiful examples of various ORMs (nHibernate, EF, LinqToSql, etc.) that implement but don't actually support the full `IQueryable<T>` interface, throwing `NotSupportedExceptions` when they encounter something they don't like, such as LinqToSql and `SkipWhile`. My question is this: why do ORM providers opt to throw a `NotSupportedException` instead of letting certain query operators (that do not translate well or at all to the target data source) trip a query execution and then let Linq to objects handle the rest?

I understand that some heavy physical resource usage could occur as a result, but if `IQueryable<T>` instances were *truly* swappable, would we not be better off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the purpose of the `IQueryable<T>` interface is also to allow differed execution of the query, i.e., the functions applied to the collection are not actually applied but converted internally, in the case of LINQ to SQL for example, in an SQL query (a `string`).

If there is no way of expressing the given function in the source, then you can't support the operation, and you better have the programmer know that by throwing the `NotSupportedException`. He might then decide to switch to a specific data structure and carry on from there, but at least he knows what he's doing.

Comment: Query execution could still be deferred. It's only when ToList or ToArray are called that the entire expression tree is evaluated, right?

Comment: Well, when the results are iterated over.

Comment: Sorry it took so long; accepting this answer because I feel that it does the best job of explaining the intent of the `IQueryable<T>` interface and how the `NotSupportedException` relates to it. And to offer up another, more concrete example: SQL Server and MongoDB are both queryable data sources, and while they both fit within that concept, they each support different features. `IQueryable<T>` is like a code representation of this notion.

Answer (score 3):

Well, because

1. You would lose control of the query process, and
2. You would get an unexpected, and inaccurate, result.

The `NotSupportedException` is there so that you, the developer, can be notified of the unsupported feature.  You can then re-work your query in some way to get the result you want, without using the unsupported feature.

Comment: Pretending for a moment that there is no such thing as a leaky abstraction, *why does it matter* if you 'lose control of the query process', and how would the result be unexpected and inaccurate so long as the return value is what the client expects?

Comment: How could the return value be what the client expects if one of the Linq functions is unsupported?  Let's say you had a calculator that didn't support the Sin function.  Would you rather it just passed the value through the Sin function unmodified (producing an inaccurate result), or would it be better to throw an error?

Comment: I would rather the IQueryProvider execute its query and then offload the calculation onto the Linq to objects provider...

Comment: @RobertHarvey The difference is, there is an obvious choice how to implement it: using LINQ to Objects. (Note that I'm saying obvious choice, not right choice.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey if I had a calculator with a Sin button that either passed the value unmodified *or* threw an error, I would return the calculator as defective.  If it didn't support Sin, it shouldn't have the button.

Comment: @DanLyons spot on.

Comment: @DanLyons: OK, but basically you're saying that an IQueryProvider that doesn't support `SkipWhile` is not an IQueryProvider at all, and you should just throw out the whole thing.  I'd rather have partial functionality than no functionality at all.  The canonical way you say that a function is not supported in an interface is to throw an `NotSupportedException`.

Comment: @tuespetre: `I would rather the IQueryProvider execute its query and then offload the calculation onto the Linq to objects provider` -- As the developer, you still have the option to do that yourself.  The difference is that you don't have some piece of software trying to do your thinking for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason is that such behavior could have very unexpected performance. Namely, if you tried to skip over most of some table, the query would need to load most of the table (or at least the relevant columns).

When the choice is between something that is unexpected and reporting error that can be easily fixed (by adding `AsEnumerable()` before the `TakeWhile()`), I think it makes sense to choose the latter.

If you don't like this, you could create your own `IQueryable` wrapper, that behaves exactly the way you want: if the underlying `IQueryable` throws `NotSupportedException`, call the equivalent method from LINQ to Objects (by using `AsEnumerable()`).

Comment: But if loading most of the data from some store is undesired, that is an implementation concern. As far as consuming code is concerned, if it calls `somethingQueryable.TakeWhile(something => something.Value > otherValue).ToList()`, it should then have an enumerable set of `somethings` to work with. I guess I just find `NotSupportedException` and `NotImplementedException` to be anti-patterns in production code, like "Hey, let's implement this interface, oh psyche, not really, but your code still builds, eh?"

Comment: @tuespetre: The only other option would be to have a proliferation of interface combinations that omit the unsupported methods.  I think it's obvious what a nightmare that would be.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think that some BCL types would be better that way (e.g. `Stream` should be separate for reading and writing, there should have been `IReadOnlyList` from the start). But I agree that `IQueryable` is not one of those cases, there is no clear way to split it into a small number of types.

Comment: Having an `IQueryable` wrapper as svick mentioned may well be the best solution I can think of... I don't know if there really is an answer to my question unless someone who has developed for the mentioned ORMs would chime in, but I am really tempted to accept this answer.

Comment: @tuespetre: Naturally, if you want different behavior, you would write a wrapper.  That's the whole point of surfacing the `NotSupportedException` in the first place; it gives you, the developer, the ability to make an informed decision.

Answer (score 0):

Because of it's complexity. If query throws `NotSupportedException` that probably means you query is extremely complex. And as such, it would be really hard to separate what can be run over DB and what must be done in-memory. In simplest way, you just fetch the whole table or maybe half of the DB, thanks to joined records. And you must be crazy to think that is good idea, especially when it happens without you knowing. Implementing such detection algorithm would be quite complex, probably even more complex than implementing query feature itself.

Also, implementing `IQueryable` is quite complex in itself (as proven by NHibernate devs), so they probably haven't had time to implement this specific feature of whole complex query system.